How to calculate the correct persistence diagram from a binary-mask-png using GUDHI
I'm trying to get the persistence diagram from a mask(for segmentation), and my codes are as follows:
import numpy as np
import gudhi as gd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL.Image import open as open

image = 1 - np.asarray(open(r'./samples/Image_01L_1stHO.png').convert('L'))
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.title("Original Image")
plt.show()

image_vector = image.flatten()

cubical_complex = gd.CubicalComplex(
    dimensions=[image.shape[0], image.shape[1]],
    top_dimensional_cells=image_vector
)

cubical_complex.compute_persistence(homology_coeff_field=2, min_persistence=0)
print(cubical_complex)

cofaces = cubical_complex.cofaces_of_persistence_pairs()

print("Cofaces of persistence pairs:", cofaces)

persistence_diagram = cubical_complex.persistence()
print("Persistence Diagram:", persistence_diagram)

gd.plot_persistence_diagram(persistence_diagram)
plt.show()

And I got:

and

It seems like there were something wrong. Even when I tried to change my png, or even I tried generated some binary masks randomly, the Persistence Diagram always showed like this, with just two red points. But it seems like the function have generated the correct cofaces_of_persistence_pairs! Then why?! Please help! Thanks!
Please tell me if I am wrong at any point!

Sorry, I found that it just happens on binary-mask-like images. When I set the image from the function np.random.random((100, 100)), it seems to be right. Then another question occurs: Isn't this topology analysis for graphical structures, why is it tied to the color of the image?    And I tried this repo: https://github.com/HuXiaoling/TopoLoss, the Topoloss is for Ground-Truth and Output-Likelihood. Shouldn't be binary image? OMG,please help!

I think the first question should be: what are you trying to compute precisely? A persistence diagram is defined for a filtration, i.e. an increasing sequence of complexes, often represented as one complex with a value associated to each cell to indicate at which step of the filtration this cell appears.
An image is interpreted as a cubical complex, with the gray level indicating the filtration value of the pixel (or vertex). With a black&white image, there are only 2 values, so only 3 complexes: empty → black → full. What you get is thus one point (black, white) for each black connected component (except one that is (black, infinity).
It is possible to define other filtrations from the image. For instance, one could define a function which, to each point in the plane, associates its distance to the closest white pixel. The persistence diagram of this new function would have almost the same number of points, all with x=0, but the y coordinate would represent the "inner radius" of the corresponding black region. Gudhi does not have code to compute this function, but if you compute it yourself and represent it as an image/array, you can feed that to CubicalPersistence or CubicalComplex.

First of all, thank you very much for your patient explanation, and I apologize for not replying for so long! However, what you said is too professional for me. I am just a poor Python-package user (not a mathematics researcher). In my understanding, a persistence diagram represents each point in a graph generating a circle with a gradually increasing radius, then producing 0D and 1D features, etc., and as the radius expands, these features disappear at specific moments. But the results I get from a black-and-white image (or perhaps a cubical complex) do not match my expectations.

Do you think my understanding of persistence diagrams is wrong, or is it my understanding of cubical complexes that is incorrect? It will lead my future learning-path. I hope to get your answer again. Thank you very much!

What you describe is essentially the Cech (or AlphaComplex or Rips) filtration. One way to compute it would be to write in an array of shape (n,2) the x and y coordinates of the white pixels (or a subset of the white pixels), and feed that to AlphaComplex. Another way, which I described in the last paragraph of the answer, is to build an array/image where the value in each pixel is the distance to the nearest white pixel and give that to Cubical. Cubical is general and deals with any function, not just distance to points (aka growing balls).

numpy.argwhere can help for the first idea, and maybe https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/ndimage.html#distance-transforms for the last one (possibly after inverting black & white in the image).

Thanks for your kind answers again, there are 3D Volume datasets in my task, which determines that I could not convert them to (n,2) array to match the AlphaComplex or Rips. So if I had to learn the difference between so-called Cech-filtration and CubicalComplex. Or do you have any other recommendations or suggestions? My goal is simply to make sure that the topological dimensions of my 3D data are consistent at some level.(Even I see someone uses the ‘cofaces_of_persistence_pairs’ function only to constraint the topology structure of binary-mask. Is that works?)

My advice works just as well in 3d, except that the shape will be (n,3). cofaces_of_persistence_pairs is only useful if you intend to compute the gradient of the persistence diagram.

@DonalHuang See https://github.com/mglisse/TDA-tutorial/blob/cub-dist/Tuto-GUDHI-Image-distance.ipynb for a 2d example.

It's really nice of u! Now I can handle the above question. Actually, it's all my fault for not learning some fundamental knowledge as well. Thank u again!

Use this code instead.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gudhi as gd
from scipy.ndimage import distance_transform_edt

def compute_persistence_diagram(binary_mask):
    global persistence
    distance = distance_transform_edt(binary_mask)
    cubical_complex = gd.CubicalComplex(dimensions=distance.shape, top_dimensional_cells=distance.flatten())
    persistence = cubical_complex.persistence()
    plot_persistence_diagram(persistence)
    
def plot_persistence_diagram(persistence):
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
    for dim, birth_death in persistence:
        if birth_death[1] != float('inf'):
            plt.scatter(birth_death[0], birth_death[1], label=f"H{dim}", alpha=0.6)
        else:
            plt.scatter(birth_death[0], birth_death[1], label=f"H{dim}", alpha=0.6, marker='x')
    max_birth_death = max(max(birth for _, (birth, _) in persistence), max(death for _, (_, death) in persistence if death != float('inf')))
    plt.plot([0, max_birth_death], [0, max_birth_death], 'k--')
    plt.xlabel("Birth")
    plt.ylabel("Death")
    plt.title("Persistence Diagram")
    plt.show()

compute_persistence_diagram(mask_pred)

